# Prove that the sequence given by $a_0 = 1/2$, $a_{n+1} = a_n -a^2_n$ converges to $0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to prove that the sequence given by $a_0 = 1/2$, $a_{n+1} = a_n -a^2_n$ converges to $0$, since I have already proved that $0<a_{n+1}<a_n$ $\forall n$? I tried to do it by contradiction saying: there exists a $\gamma > 0$ such that $a_n \longrightarrow \gamma$, but I'm not able to finish the proof.

Comment: Hint: $\gamma=\gamma-\gamma^2$ (why?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_0=\frac12$, we can show that $a_n\leqslant\frac1{2^n}$ for all $n$ using induction. Clearly this is true for $n=0$. Assume that $a_n\leqslant\frac1{2^n}$ for some $n\geqslant 0$, then
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n-a_n^2 \leqslant \frac1{2^n} - \frac1{2^{n+1}} = \frac1{2^{n+1}}.
$$
Since $a_0=\frac12>0$, similarly by induction we have $a_n^2<a_n$ and hence $a_n-a_n^2>0$ for all $n$. It follows that $a_n>0$ for all $n$. Now, given $\varepsilon>0$, choose a positive integer $N > \frac{\log 2}{\log\varepsilon}$. Then for $N\geqslant n$, we have $$a_n\leqslant \frac1{2^n} <\varepsilon,$$
which implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

Comment: well, no: 1  a_n  0.25  log 2  -2  //  
2  a_n  0.1875  log 2  -2.415037499278844  //  
3  a_n  0.15234375  log 2  -2.714597781137752  //  
4  a_n  0.1291351318359375  log 2  -2.953046548693273  //  
5  a_n  0.1124592495616525  log 2  -3.152525769939353  //  
6  a_n  0.09981216674968249  log 2  -3.324640504076233  //  
7  a_n  0.08984969811841607  log 2  -3.476342533271513  //  
8  a_n  0.08177672986644557  log 2  -3.612165817052166  //  
9  a_n  0.07508929631879596  log 2  -3.735248917832095  //  
10  a_n  0.06945089389714401  log 2  -3.847862926631017  //

Comment: @WillJagy I cannot read that, can you format it with MathJax?

Comment: posted answer..

Answer (score 5):

It's monotone and bounded, hence converges.  Then we get $\gamma=\gamma-\gamma^2$ by taking limits.  Hence $\gamma=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove this is to prove that $a_n = 2^{-(n+1)}$ by induction.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for math1000, who said that he could not read my comment. Two of the answers given seem to believe that $a_n$ is less than or equal to $2^{-n}.$ This is not the case, as can be seen from the simple calculations below.

```
Thu Jan 16 10:49:43 PST 2020

 \>=   means greater than or equal to 
 n: 1  ; a_n :  1 / 4  >=    1 / 4
 n: 2  ; a_n :  3 / 16  >=    1 / 8
 n: 3  ; a_n :  39 / 256  >=    1 / 8
 n: 4  ; a_n :  8463 / 65536  >=    1 / 8
 n: 5  ; a_n :  483008799 / 4294967296  >=    1 / 16
 n: 6  ; a_n :  1841209495473815103 / 18446744073709551616  >=    1 / 16
 n: 7  ; a_n :  30574267942866411492610617989187955839 / 340282366920938463463374607431768211456  >=    1 / 16
Thu Jan 16 10:49:43 PST 2020
```